# Questions about network protocols

Tags: discussion, scope

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/response-for-ip-record-route-option is a question about a concrete network protocol (the TCP/IP family). Are such questions on-topic here?

If the question was about the implementation of the protocol in a particular operating system, it would be clearly off-topic. For example, if the question was about the `traceroute` utility, I'd close it without hesitation. Conversely, if the question was about network modeling, or about the design of network protocols, it would be squarely on-topic. This is an intermediate case. What do we want to do about it?

Comment: There is currently no other Stack Exchange site where network protocols are on-topic (see [How can we improve moderation of IP networking questions on Stack Overflow and associated sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88047/how-can-we-improve-moderation-of-ip-networking-questions-on-stack-overflow-and-a)). However this need not influence our stance as a community. We're not looking for a site to place the question, we're deciding whether it's on-topic here.

Comment: I am torn. I think it's too concrete for a science site (there is an easy "science" answer: just send some package back! So the problem is with the implementation.), but on the other hand, we *were* taught TCP/IP in a CS class at university.

Comment: @Raphael Programming classes, sometimes even IT or typing classes, often fall under the heading of CS, so that's not a good argument. I don't think you can dismiss the question as “too concrete” so easily. For example, we do accept questions about semantics of concrete programming languages, not just about language design.